# How to clearTimeout so that I can re use the function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, cleartimeout

So far, this(code below) allows me to delay my function that displays a response for 4 seconds after I click a button. Now I would like to know how I would reset this timout so that I can re-click the button for the delay to occur.

js:

```
var ball = document.getElementById("ball"); 

    function start(){
        console.log("start");
        ball.classList.toggle("shake");
}; 

    ball.addEventListener("click", start);

function newResponse() { 
     var question = document.getElementById("question").value;
     var response = ["..."];

     for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {

     var randomResponse = Math.floor(Math.random() * response.length);
        document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = response[randomResponse];
     }
}

ball.addEventListener("click", newResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function *outside* the timeout so you can reference it multiple times. Then, call `setTimeout` with the function, assign the result to a variable, and if you want to clear the timeout, call `clearTimeout` on that variable:

```
function newResponse() { 
  var question = document.getElementById("question").value;
  var response = ["..."];
  for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {       
    var randomResponse = Math.floor(Math.random() * response.length);
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = 
      response[randomResponse];
  }
}
// Set the timeout once:
let timeout = setTimeout(newResponse,4000);
// Clear it:
clearTimeout(timeout);
// Set the timeout again:
timeout = setTimeout(newResponse,4000);
// etc
```

Comment: This didn't work. After clicking the button, it would give me one response and another response after 4 second but I only want it to give me a response when I click the button.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't clearing the timeout properly - are you calling `clearTimeout` on a variable in persistent scope? Can you post the code you're using for the click listener?

Comment: I edited my question to show you how it looks like without the timeout. I also dont want to delay the function of 'start' . Just to clarify, my goal here is to make a 4 second delay for the newResponse each time I click on a ball. If there is another way to do this please let me know.

Comment: I don't see where you're trying to clear the timeout, but I'd guess that you're not setting the timeout to a persistent variable. Make sure to declare `timeout` in the outer scope, and assign to it (don't declare to it again) when calling `setTimeout`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it. I basically just copied and pasted what you put after my function (same as you did). I just started learning javascript a a month ago and I don't know much yet.

Comment: If you want the click listener to be the one to start the timeout, then out `timeout = setTimeout(newResponse, 4000)` inside the click listener, as well as `clearTimeout(timeout)` at the top, where `timeout` is declared outside.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#test').click(function(){

   var timer = setTimeout(function newResponse() { 

        alert('Click answered...');

        clearTimeout(timer);
    },4000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="test" id='test'/>
```

You can do like this

```
var timer = setTimeout(function newResponse() { 

        var question = document.getElementById("question").value;

        var response = ["..."];


    for (var i = 0; i < question.length; i++) {       

     var randomResponse = Math.floor(Math.random() * response.length);
            document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = 
            response[randomResponse];
        }

    clearTimeout(timer);
    },4000)
```

Comment: When I tried this, the button would only work once and then would not respond afterwards.